# Fetching unmatch records in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I took 2 lookups to read 2 excel files and connected to 2 for each activities and inside i have taken 2 set variable and given @item.id
Now i have to eliminate the matching records and only unmatched records has to store in a new variable

I have tried if condition and given the expression if(equals(setvariable1,setvariable2),null,setvariable1)

But its not working
1st table

```
Name  id
Ganesh 1
Vivek  2
Lah    3
```

2nd table

```
Name  id
Ganesh 1
Vivek  2
Man    3
```

Required output

```
Man  3
Lah  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add 2 source datasets one for each of the data
2. Add derived column transformation to each of the sources and create a new column called 'hashing' with the expression: "crc32(Name,Id)"
3. Add Assert transformation to both the branches and select assert type as 'Expect exists' and provide 'hashing1'=='hashing2' in the expression for the first assert and 'hashing2'=='hashing1' in the first assert
4. Add Alter row transformation and set condition as 'Delete if' = `not(hasError('assert1'))` and `not(hasError('assert2'))` respectively in both the branches
5. Add Select transformation in both the branches and from first branch remove all columns except : 'source1@Name' and 'source1@Id'
   From second branch, remove all columns except 'source2@Name' and 'source2@Id'
6. Add Union Transformation to union both the branches
7. Add Sink transformation to load the output to destination file/table

[image]

```
{
"name": "dataflow12",
"properties": {
    "type": "MappingDataFlow",
    "typeProperties": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText21",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "source1"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText22",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "source2"
            }
        ],
        "sinks": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "sink1"
            }
        ],
        "transformations": [
            {
                "name": "derivedColumn1"
            },
            {
                "name": "derivedColumn2"
            },
            {
                "name": "assert1"
            },
            {
                "name": "assert2"
            },
            {
                "name": "alterRow1"
            },
            {
                "name": "alterRow2"
            },
            {
                "name": "select1"
            },
            {
                "name": "select2"
            },
            {
                "name": "union1"
            }
        ],
        "scriptLines": [
            "source(output(",
            "          Name as string,",
            "          Id as string",
            "     ),",
            "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
            "     validateSchema: false,",
            "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
            "source(output(",
            "          Name as string,",
            "          Id as string",
            "     ),",
            "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
            "     validateSchema: false,",
            "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source2",
            "source1 derive(hashing1 = crc32(Name,Id)) ~> derivedColumn1",
            "source2 derive(hashing2 = crc32(Name,Id)) ~> derivedColumn2",
            "derivedColumn1, derivedColumn2 assert(expectExists(hashing1 == hashing2, false, 'assert1')) ~> assert1",
            "derivedColumn2, derivedColumn1 assert(expectExists(hashing2 == hashing1, false, 'assert2')) ~> assert2",
            "assert1 alterRow(deleteIf(not(hasError('assert1')))) ~> alterRow1",
            "assert2 alterRow(deleteIf(not(hasError('assert2')))) ~> alterRow2",
            "alterRow1 select(mapColumn(",
            "          Name = source1@Name,",
            "          Id = source1@Id",
            "     ),",
            "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
            "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
            "alterRow2 select(mapColumn(",
            "          Name = source2@Name,",
            "          Id = source2@Id",
            "     ),",
            "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
            "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2",
            "select1, select2 union(byName: true)~> union1",
            "union1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
            "     validateSchema: false,",
            "     deletable:false,",
            "     insertable:true,",
            "     updateable:false,",
            "     upsertable:false,",
            "     format: 'table',",
            "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
            "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
            "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide json

Comment: I have added the video and json. You can make changes for the source and sink dataset names etc

Comment: Actually i need with out dataflow

Comment: @ManiKanta - the next step is for you to edit your question and show your actual details. Your question is just a general description, with some data. You're now asking someone to revise the solution (that shouldn't have even provided) to be custom-tailored. This is not how Stack Overflow works - it's for asking specific questions and providing answers, not "build a custom solution based on my requirements."

Comment: @AnnuKumari - best not to answer off-topic questions that have no specific detail (just compare what the OP wrote in their question - essentially just a description - to what you wrote, a full custom solution. You shouldn't post a custom solution like this (and you've now seen what it's led to)

Comment: Yeah i have given what i have tried so i think they may continue. Appologies that i missed that i will give more proper from next time. Thanks for the info

Comment: @DavidMakogon,i'm just asking Appologies if i have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To Fetch the Missing records in azure data factory you need to use filter activity .

Follow the below steps:

- Take 2 LookUps each of a on excel file as below:
  [image]
- After Each lookup Take Filter activity to get Missing record from that file.
  with below expressions:

```json
--For table 1
items - @activity('Lookup1').output.value
Condition - @not(contains(activity('Lookup2').output.value,item()))

--For table 2
items - @activity('Lookup2').output.value
Condition - @not(contains(activity('Lookup1').output.value,item()))
```

[image]
This will filter out the missing records.

- Now take variable with array type and expression as `@union(activity('Filter_for_table1').output.value,activity('Filter_for_table2').output.value)`
  [image]
  This will result you expected output as below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: As I commented on the other answer: the question is off-topic and has no specifics. There is no justification for writing a custom solution for an incomplete question.

Comment: pratik lad and annukumari  thanks for the solution